# "ResolutionError: The key 'repositories.xxxxxx.XxxxxRepository' is not bound to any value in context" Error in Production application

Tags: node.js, loopback4

Loopback4 application deployed in server and running successfully. After N number of days, its throwing following error:

```
ResolutionError: The key 'repositories.xxxxxx.XxxxxRepository' is not bound 
to any value in context RequestContext-WWxEGiXRTMCChN1MiK2iPw-8 (context: 
RequestContext-WWxEGiXRTMCChN1MiK2iPw-8, binding: 
repositories.xxxxxx.XxxxxRepository, resolutionPath: 
controllers.XxxxController --> @XxxxController.constructor[1])
```

For all incoming requests throwing this error after N number of days.

As per our understanding, the binding key `'repositories.xxxxxx.XxxxxRepository'` value is not available in the context registry.

How can this happen after N number of days in Prod application ??

We are binding the Value to the key `'repositories.xxxxxx.XxxxxRepository'` at starting of application(application level).

More Info: server - REST API server.